# Integrate Supersized into a custom Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know how to integrate the supersized jQuery plugin into a custom wordpress theme. I inlcuded all of the scripts and stylesheets yet it would not work.

Any thoughts?

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Thanks!

Jesse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this plugin installation [WP Supersized](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-supersized/)

You can also follow these tutorial links, I hope this is what you need and let me know.

1. [WordPress + Supersized, the right way](http://garvinmedia.com/2011/04/wordpress-supersized-the-right-way/)
2. [How to integrate Supersized in wordpress](http://www.worldinmyeyes.be/1534/)